# does word-wrap: break-word working in Vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin, word-wrap

I have a textarea inside a table, and i set

> .v-textarea{
>       word-wrap: break-word; }

in css. and there is no other style override it. but it seems not working. is there anyway else to break the work? or did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Link to your page, so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: What browser are you testing with? At least Safari has break-word as the default for text areas, and it's working as expected.

Comment: @Jouni I use chrome and ff, and I finally got it working using word-break: break-all. don't know how..

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin table have two states: editable and "normal". As I understand you set CSS style only for table in editable state, than your should add another style for your table in "normal" state.

```
.v-table-cell-content .v-table-cell-break-word{
word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

If your want set this style only for specific column use this:

```
table.setCellStyleGenerator(new CellStyleGenerator() {
public String getStyle(Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
 if (propertyId == null){
  return null;
 }
 if (propertyId.equals("your.column.name")) {
  // style the generated email column
  return "break-word";
 }
}};
```

For more information your can see [this tutotial](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#TableRowStyling).

Comment: thanks, I will try that. but I got it working using word-break: break-all; Don't know the differences..